# Do I need a bike bag / box to put my bike on the Eurostar?

Tags: uk, public-transportation, europe, transportation

The Eurostar website has a page that really should say but doesn't:

http://www.eurostar.com/UK/uk/leisure/travel_information/at_the_station/bicycles.jsp

I'm guessing I don't?

Would also be interested in any other experiences/hints/tips anyone has for transporting bikes on the Eurostar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That page actually lays it out pretty well. You have three options: box/bag your bike, pay £30 for a reserved bike space, or pay £22 to ship your bike such that it will arrive within 24 hours of you.

The reserved bike spaces and shipping don't require you to box or bag your bike.

When I traveled on EuroStar and on French trains, I had a friend handy with a sewing machine make me a [housse](https://www.google.com/search?q=housse+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=bike+cover) out of lightweight ripstop nylon. By turning the handlebars sideways and removing the pedals and wheels I was able to get it mostly within the size restrictions - it was bulky but fit in the luggage area, which is all that matters. It was slightly longer and wider than allowed but no one checked.